# Isn't `void f(A<0>, tuple<T *...>)` more specialized than `void f(A<I>, tuple<T *...>)`?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, compiler-errors, overloading

```
#include <tuple>

template<int I>
struct A {};

template<int I, typename... T>
void f(A<I>, std::tuple<T *...>) {}

template<typename... T>
void f(A<0>, std::tuple<T *...>) {}

int main()
{
    f(A<0>{}, std::tuple<char*, int*, float*>{});
}
```

Isn't the second overload of `f` more specialized? g++ 4.9.2 says that the call is ambiguous, clang 3.6.0 accepts it. Which compiler is right?

It's interesting that if you change `std::tuple<T *...>` to `std::tuple<T...>`, g++ is fine with it, which I don't understand.

Comment: MSVC 2013 is also happy with this:)

Comment: I suspect gcc is wrong, but there could be something obscure about value template parameters (the standard tends to be quirky around them).  Can you repo without using values?

Comment: [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) is also OK with the code.

Comment: @Yakk [Repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97326f6a7606dd22) using types.

Answer (score 5):

By the current rules, the second overload is more specialized. Some specialization `A<@>` with a synthesized value `@` cannot be matched against `A<0>`, but `A<0>` can be matched against `A<I>` (with `I=0`). This first pair's asymmetry is decisive. Whether you use `T` or `T*` as the pattern in the second parameter is irrelevant, as deduction succeeds both ways for that pair.

The bug still persists in trunk and was reported by @Barry as [67228](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67228).

Comment: Note: The resolution CWG 1391 might make this ambiguous. I'm unsure about that though.

Comment: Yeah the resolution isn't quite right I think. Check out bogdan's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31735126/2069064), I think he has some good ideas of how to actually resolve the wordings.