# Overload resolution and explicit template arguments

Tags: c++, template-specialization, overload-resolution

The following code [prints "func 2"](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MbbkopXLI3rwlXL5).

Why does the compiler treat the second template as a better match, in presence of explicit (not deduced) template arguments? Why is there no ambiguity?

I'd appreciate quotations from the C++ standard.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
void func(T)
{
    std::cout << "func 1\n";
}

template<class T>
void func(typename identity<T>::type)
{
    std::cout << "func 2\n";
}

int main()
{
    func<int>(1);    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both candidates are viable and take identical arguments, so the overload resolution process falls back to the last tiebreaker: partial ordering of function templates [[temp.func.order]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order).

The rule is that we synthesize a new type for each template type parameter and attempt to perform deduction on each other overload. For `1`, we synthesize a type `Unique1`, which fails deduction on `2` because `T` is a non-deduced context. For `2`, we synthesize a type `Unique2`, which succeeds deducing `T = typename identity<Unique2>::type`. Since deduction succeeds in one direction and not the other, that makes `2` more specialized than `1`, hence it's preferred.

Note that template partial ordering rules are somewhat incomplete in the standard. If you simply add another argument of type `T`, the preference [flips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394260/2069064).