# overload resolution of template function with auto

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, overloading

With the 3 following overloads

```
template <class T> auto foo() { return 1; }
template <class T> int  foo() { return 2; }
template <class T> T    foo() { return 3; }
```

Is the following ill formed ?

```
static_cast<int(*)()>(&foo<int>)();
```

Clang selects overload #2, whereas gcc fails to compile ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f805467081c1c419))

When removing overload #1, both agree to select overload #2 ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82de6eb2336a5282)).

When removing overload #2, gcc selects overload #1 and clang fails to compile ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28428c56e6e77756))

Comment: Isn't defining 1 and 2 in the same translation unit an ODR violation?

Comment: If "auto" is translated as "int" then #1 and #2 are the same, yes? Not prefered candidate. Clang seems to consider #2 more specialized than #1 and #1 and #3 the same specialization; ambiguous selection again. I would say that gcc is right and Clang is wrong due to "auto" should not participate in overload resolutions.

Comment: @user657267 Return types are part of function templates' signatures. The above declarations provide different *declared* return types, so the signatures differ. That the actual return types coincide is irrelevant.

Comment: Great question. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [[over.over]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#2), we perform template argument deduction. This will succeed for all three overloads: in the first one, keep [[temp.deduct.funcaddr]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr#2) in mind:

> A placeholder type (7.1.7.4) in the return type of a function template is a non-deduced context. If template
>   argument deduction succeeds for such a function, the return type is determined from instantiation of the
>   function body.

Since the deduction will succeed (given that all template parameters have explicitly supplied arguments), the return type is deduced as `int`. In the second case, deduction succeeds since the argument is provided, and in the third, `T` will be deduced. <sup>†</sup>

Going on to [paragraph 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#4),

> If more than one function is selected, [...] any given
>   function template specialization `F1` is eliminated if the set contains
>   a second function template specialization whose function template is
>   more specialized than the function template of `F1` according to the
>   partial ordering rules of 14.5.6.2. **After such eliminations**, if any, **there shall remain exactly one selected function.**

According to [[temp.deduct.partial]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#3), the function templates' function types are used for partial ordering. We can immediately see that #1 and #2's function types do not contain any template parameters that participate in deduction, hence via the addition to [[temp.deduct.partial]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#4) introduced by core issue [1391](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1391)'s resolution, their corresponding `P`s are not used to determine the ordering. @bogdan explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735126/3647361) why that resolution is problematic; the bottom line is that ordering just yields an ambiguity for #1 and #2.

That is, according to current (probably defective) wording, the conversion is ill-formed in all cases. If partial ordering is fixed for pairs of non-dependent/deducing parameters,

- case 1 and 3 are ambiguous, because for two non-dependent function types (the ones of #1 and #2), there is no ordering pair.
- the accepting behavior in case 2 is correct (as expected).

---

<sup>†</sup> [[temp.deduct.type]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#8) element 9 (`T()`), in case you were curious.

Comment: Chapeau. Really interesting. You know the standard by heart and it scares me a bit anyway... :-) +1