# Does partial ordering is used to select the more specialized template?

Tags: c++, partial-ordering

There are multiple questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17005985/19479518) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394260/19479518) regarding partial ordering. But they all cover the process of partial ordering and when it occurs.

The point of my question lies in this paragraph on the standard:

> If multiple function templates share a name, the use of that name can
> be ambiguous because template argument deduction ([temp.deduct]) may
> identify a specialization for more than one function template. Partial
> ordering of overloaded function template declarations is used in the
> following contexts to select the function template to which a function
> template specialization refers:
>
> - (1.1) during overload resolution for a call to a function template specialization ([over.match.best]);
> - (1.2) when the address of a function template specialization is taken;
> - (1.3) when a placement operator delete that is a function template specialization is selected to match a placement operator new
>   ([basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation], [expr.new]);
> - (1.4) when a friend function declaration, an explicit instantiation or an explicit specialization refers to a function template
>   specialization.

[[temp.func.order]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#1)

It's clear from this paragraph that partial ordering **is used in the above contexts to select the function template to which a function template specialization refers**.

So if I have example:

```
template <class T> void f(T);  // T1  
template <class T> void f(T*); // T2

f((int*)0); // bullet 1.1 applies 

// the implicit specializations could be:
// template <> void f<int*>(int*); // F1
// template <> void f<int>(int*);  // F2
```

From the bold part above, and in my example, partial ordering is *just* used to ensure that F1 refers to T1 and F2 refers to T2 without any ambigiuty. Right?

Does this the only use of partial ordering? does it used to select the more specialized template?

---

EDIT

I just added another example to ensure that the order of events is correct.

```
template <class T> void f(const T&); // T1: 
template <class T> void f(T*);       // T2:

f((int*)0);

// the compiler may be generates:
// template <> void f(int* const&); // F1 
// template <> void f(int*);        // F2
```

1- because the call `f((int*)0)` matches the bullet `1.1`, partial ordering occurs.

2- partial ordering ensures that the name of specialization `F1` does match more than function template. That's F1 refers only T1. The same check is occur for F2: F2 refers to T2 only.

3- The overload set contains F1 and F2. Both ICS(F1) and ICS(F2) are identity conversions. Here neither rule in [[over.ics.rank]/3/3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2) is applied.

4- Then the compiler goes to the next step to check the rules defined in [[over.match.best.general]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2). Bullet 2.5 is applied since F1 and F2 are function template specializations. Then partial ordering rules ([temp.func.order]) are applied to check the more specialized template.

These steps I follow when I encounter a call to an overloaded template. Do these steps are true? Does the order of these steps are consistent?

Do steps 1 and 2 are redundant?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "Does this the only use of partial ordering?" As opposed to what?

Comment: @BrianBi - From the quote I provided: "_[..] Partial ordering of overloaded function template declarations is used in the following contexts to select the function template to which a function template specialization [..]_ So it said that it used to select function template to which a function template specialization. So in my example, I think partial ordering is just used to ensure that `F1` refers to only one function template (`T1`) and `F2` to only one function template (`T2`) so that F1 and F2 names are not ambiguous.

Comment: @BrianBi .... so it seems from the standard this is the only use of partial ordering: just to ensure that the name of specialization doesn't refer to more than one function template. So I am asking does this the only use of partial ordering? So what about selecting a more specialized template? Isn't this the job of partial ordering?